# Non-public constructor causing problems with Tomcat7?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, runtime-error

I have Java app with Spring running on tomcat.

This class is causing a very strange problem for me:

```
@WebListener
public class ThreadPool extends ThreadPoolExecutor implements ServletContextListener {

  private ThreadPool() {
    super(MIN_ACTIVE_THREADS, MAX_ACTIVE_THREADS, DEACTIVATE_THREADS_AFTER_TIMEPERIOD, TimeUnit.SECONDS, taskQueue);
  }

  private static final ThreadPoolExecutor pool = new ThreadPool();

  public synchronized static void submit(Task task) {
      executingTasks.add(task);
      pool.execute(task);
  }

  @Override
  public synchronized void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    cancelWaitingTasks();
    sendStopSignalsToExecutingTasks();
    pool.shutdown();
  }

  ...

}
```

If the constructor is private or default I get this exception during runtime (on first HTTP request to the app):

```
Error configuring application listener of class com.testApp.util.ThreadPool
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager can not access a member of class com.testApp.util.ThreadPool with modifiers "private"
    at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:102)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:436)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4888)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
Error listenerStart
Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
```

But if i set the constructor public then I get no exceptions and everything works fine. Can anyone tell me why is this default or private constructor causing runtime exceptions?

Comment: are you calling it somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomcat's `org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager` is trying to create an object of your `ThreadPool` which you have configured as context listener. Now, since this is outside of `org.apache.catalina.core` you have to use a public constructor else `org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager`  will not be able to create its object.

From `org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager`

```
private Object newInstance(Object instance, Class<?> clazz) throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, NamingException {
    if (!ignoreAnnotations) {
        Map<String, String> injections = injectionMap.get(clazz.getName());
        processAnnotations(instance, injections);
        postConstruct(instance, clazz);
    }
    return instance;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Tomcat uses `Class.newInstance()` to create an instance of your `ThreadPool`. This method obeys the access rules of Java.

Since your constructor is private it fails with a `IllegalAccessException`. This is the runtime equivalent of not being allowed to call a function to the compiler error which you see if you would try to write `new ThreadPool()` outside of `ThreadPool`,

Answer (score 1):

Through the error, it said clearly because it cannot access a member of class.

```
can not access a member of class com.testApp.util.ThreadPool with modifiers
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I accidentally discovered the real reason I was getting exceptions. Currently I am using this class, no exceptions thrown, tested on GlassFish and Tomcat:

```
public class TrackingThreadPool extends ThreadPoolExecutor {

    private static final int MAX_WAITING_TASKS = 4000;
    private static final int MAX_ACTIVE_THREADS = 20;
    private static final int MIN_ACTIVE_THREADS = 4;
    private static final int DEACTIVATE_THREADS_AFTER_SECONDS = 60;

    private TrackingThreadPool() {
        super(MIN_ACTIVE_THREADS, MAX_ACTIVE_THREADS, DEACTIVATE_THREADS_AFTER_SECONDS,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS, waitingTasks);
    }

    private static final BlockingQueue<Runnable> waitingTasks = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(MAX_WAITING_TASKS);

    private static final Map<Long, Task> executingTasks = new HashMap<>(MAX_ACTIVE_THREADS * 2);

    private static final TrackingThreadPool instance = new TrackingThreadPool();

    public synchronized static void submitAndTrack(Task task) {
        executingTasks.put(task.getId(), task);
        instance.execute(task);
    }

    public synchronized static void shutdownAndCancelAllTasks() {
        cancelWaitingTasks();
        sendStopSignalToExecutingTasks();
        instance.shutdown();
    }

    @Override
    protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
        super.afterExecute(r, t);
        if (r instanceof Task) {
            executingTasks.remove(((Task) r).getId());
        }
    }

private static void cancelWaitingTasks() {
    List<Runnable> waitingTaskListRunnables = new ArrayList<>(waitingTasks.size() + 10); //+10 to avoid resizing
    waitingTasks.drainTo(waitingTaskListRunnables);
    for (Runnable r : waitingTaskListRunnables) {
        if (r instanceof Task) {
            ((Task) r).sendStopSignal(byShutdownMethod());
        }
    }
}

    private static void sendStopSignalToExecutingTasks() {
        for (long taskId : executingTasks.keySet()) {
            Task executingTask = executingTasks.get(taskId);
            executingTask.sendStopSignal(byShutdownMethod());
        }
    }

    private static String byShutdownMethod() {
        return TrackingThreadPool.class.getSimpleName() + "#shutdownAndCancelAllTasks()";
    }
}
```

And if I swap the positions of `BlockingQueue<Runnable> waitingTasks` and `TrackingThreadPool instance` like this:

```
private static final TrackingThreadPool instance = new TrackingThreadPool();

private static final Map<Long, Task> executingTasks = new HashMap<>(MAX_ACTIVE_THREADS * 2);

private static final BlockingQueue<Runnable> waitingTasks = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(MAX_WAITING_TASKS);
```

I get exceptions again because `waitingTasks` is not instantiated by the time I make a new `TrackingThreadPool` instance.

I guess you can have a subclass of `ThreadPoolExecutor` with a private constructor / singelton pattern.

Comment: Buddy, you got good stuff but not got it entirely right .. Now, with the new class you have posted in your answer use `implements ServletContextListener` in class declaration and again you will get the same exception you posted in your answer because your constructor is private and I have explained the reason in my answer .. So basically if you are implementing `ServletContextListener` and not making the class constructor as public then you will get the issue .. And this is what your primary problem was for which you had posted the question for ..

Comment: The swapping thing has nothing to do with `java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager can not access a member of class com.testApp.util.ThreadPool with modifiers "private"` .. Think about it how it could possibly relate to access modifiers ..